# Angular throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined" with password input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm getting the following error when submitting the form.

It seems to be related to the input type being set to `"password"` as the error doesn't occur if I change the type to `"text"`.  Strangely, I have found that this error doesn't show up when I add another input, such as email.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error with Angular 1.5.6 and UI-Router 0.3.1. Which browser and which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: It's working fine in `angular 1.2.1`, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/sdq451m0/

Comment: @JariJokinen, I'm using Angular 1.6.1, UI-Router 0.3.2, and Chrome 55.0.2883.95.

Comment: It might also be worthy of note that I am using `angular-rails-templates`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking further into this, I realized the error is coming from the Okta password manager that I recently installed and has nothing to do inherently with the code.